# Masturbation is Haram in Islam in the Light of Quran and Hadith

Tags: masturbation

Because I am jobless at the age of 28 and I am unmarried, my parents don't think I am ready for marriage. Sometimes I see a girl who just crossed in front of me, or just passes beside me and she is beautiful. After seeing her, I feel as if I could have sex with her. When these thoughts occur, I become erect and I want to fulfill my lust.

I know it can't be possible because it is Haram in Islam to do Zina, at the same time it is also a bitter truth that I want to satisfy myself. In order to not go towards Zina, I try to satisfy myself with masturbation.

In that condition is it Haram?

Answer (score -1):

There is difference of opinion among scholars whether masturbations' is sin or not. There are scholars who said هو ماؤك فأهرقه ( it is your water, so pour it out). I don't remember the reference.

For most of boys, if they don't masturbate, they will end up having nocturnal emission. it is similar to masturbation in dream. I don't understand how some deed done during dream can be halal and the same when done otherwise is haram.

Allah knows best.

Comment: Please refrain from re-posting the same answer to multiple questions; in cases where the same question is asked multiple times, the question itself should be closed as a duplicate so all the answers can be found and judged in one place.